# HIVE: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: hadoop, hive

I setup HIVE in my system. When I am running normal queries like below, queries are executing fine.

```
   select * from employee;
   select * from employee where age=29
```

But when I ran with distinct keyword, I am getting following error.

```
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
```

Apart from plain queries, most of the HiveQL statement are getting failed with the same error (Ex: ***insert into table employee1 select * from employee limit 5***)
Can I know, how to find out the root cause and probable solutions here..

Comment: Find the mapreduce task logs in the yarn UI for the actual error

Comment: Do you have the application_id for that job? With it, you can check Yarn for the real cause behind that Code 2 error, by running the following command:

`yarn logs -applicationId <your_application_id> -log_files stderr`
  
                                                                    . Like @OneCricketeer said, you can also check in Yarn UI for the job logs. And, if you are using HUE, you can also look at the logs with Hue Job Browser.